# Why does this code only work with jQuery v1.4.4?

Tags: jquery

The hide function doesn't work in the following code with newer version of jQuery. It only works with jQuery v1.4.4. The PHP code is OK.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<!--THIS CODE DOESN'T WORK IF I USE NEWER VERSION OF JQUERY LIKE 1.11.0.min.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modal-window.js"></script>
<script>
    function ajax_cancel() {
        var id_org = $('#org').val();
        var id_user = "<?php echo $user_id; ?>";
        $.ajax({
            url: 'cancel.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'id_org=' + id_org + '&id_user=' + id_user,
            dataType: 'text/html',
            success: function () {
                $("#vent_modal_e" + id_org).hide(); //THIS LINE ONLY WORKS WITH JQUERY v1.4.4. DOESN´T WORK WITH NEWER VERSIONS.
            }
        })
    };
</script>
```

Comment: What doesn't work, specifically? What does it do instead?

Comment: I think you could of just posted the ajax call that doesn't work in 1.4.4. As it is the only relevant code in your question

Comment: Come on now.  "Doesn't work" is a woefully insufficient description.  Tells us exactly what steps you take in the app, what you expect to have happen, what happens instead, what errors show in the error log and be very specific, naming specific objects in your HTML where appropriate and particular lines of javascript as needed.

Comment: It does nothing. The line that I want to hide, doesn't hide. The modal window Works ok, and cancel.php also Works ok. I get no error on the console.     $("#vent_modal_e" + id_org).hide(); //THIS LINE ONLY WORKS WITH JQUERY v1.4.4. DOESN´T HIDE WITH NEWER VERSIONS.

Comment: I had an error here: dataType: 'text/html'. It should be        dataType: 'html'. With this change Works ok. Sorry if I made the question too extensive or confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the script code always inside the `document.ready()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Your script code goes here.
});
```

or

```
$(function(){
    //Your script code goes here.
});
```